# showBottomModalSheet function works on iOS emulator but not Android

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I have this function that adds an entry to a SQLite database and it works perfectly on my iOS emulator but the button click does nothing on my Android emulator:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15,
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                // this will prevent the soft keyboard from covering the text fields
                /// bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 160,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 360,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _exercisenameController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Exercise Name',
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
                      LimitRange(1, 10000),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: _totalweightController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Weight'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
                      LimitRange(1, 10000),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: _totalrepsController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Reps'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    //button to confirm entry
                    onPressed: () async {
                      //if else check that none of the entries are empty
                      if (_exercisenameController.text.isEmpty ||
                          _totalweightController.text.isEmpty ||
                          _totalrepsController.text.isEmpty) {
                        print('Do you even lift');

                        /* AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Do you even lift'),
                          content: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: ListBody(
                              children: const <Widget>[
                                Text('All Input fields must be filled.'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            TextButton(
                              child: const Text('OK'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );*/
                      } else {
                        //Save new journal
                        if (id == null) {
                          //if the item doesnt exist
                          await _addItem();
                        }

                        if (id != null) {
                          //if it exists update it instead
                          await _updateItem(id);
                        }

                        // Clear the text fields
                        _exercisenameController.text = '';
                        _totalweightController.text = '';
                        _totalrepsController.text = '';

                        //closing the popup
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
                    },
                    //the text of the button change depending on if its new or updating an existing
                    child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
```

I expected it to work on the Android emulator like it did on the iOS emulator. It should be creating the database and then when I press *create item* elevated button it should be adding an entry to the database.

Comment: Sorry I am new, how do i format this

Comment: The easiest way to format source code is to use an *Integrated Development Environment*. Several web-based platforms support such, too. [dart.dev provides guidance](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) (and a tool or two).